# How to get multiple VM metric details in a single Azure Rest API Call

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement where I need to fetch metrics values from multiple servers using single Azure rest API(I need to make only one API call instead of calling multiple times).

How can I achieve this using C#?

I have already created a class that fetches the metrics values of a single VM. Following is the code for that:

```
class Program
    {
        string tenantId;
        string token;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Metrics metrics = new Metrics();
            var pg = new Program();
            pg.token = pg.GetAccessToken();
            string output = pg.doGET("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/d849b9f5-7a60-40fc-acb6-81d1955aa423/resourceGroups/Test_G/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/helloazuretest215/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01", pg.token);
            //metrics.metricAvailabilities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Metrics>(output).metricAvailabilities;
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/33d5de17-8fff-4150-b93c-fbec078c02b6/oauth2/token";
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "052d8ab3-9184-4e46-aaff-20c3d650397g", clientSecret: "azure123");
            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://myazureapp.app.com", clientCredential: credential);
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }
            token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }

        private string doGET(string URI, String token)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(URI));
            // Create the request
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            // Get the response
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error from : " + uri + ": " + ex.Message,
                                "HttpWebResponse exception");
                return null;
            }
            string result = null;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out with this requirement?

Comment: Please show your existing code.

Comment: posted the code now.

Comment: What does `I need to fetch metrics values from multiple servers` mean? If you want to get the multiple vm metrics,you could get the metrics of each vm and add it to a list and return the list.

Comment: I mean, I wanted to make a single call to the rest api, which gives me the metrics details of different VM's. For example, if I have 2 VM's. If I want to fetch metric details of those 2 VM's for a certain period of time and display it. I wanted to make only one Rest API call to fetch the details of those 2 VM's instead of making two seperate API calls.

Comment: Based on my experience, you need to implement it youself. As I mentioned that you could implement it in your API(still need to call mutiple times in the rest API). But from the client you just need to call one time, pg.doGET.

Comment: @Tom Sun, Thanks for your response. Is there a way to send multiple URI's to a single web request to make this happen. Don't feel bad if my question sounds too silly. I am totally new to this stuff.

Comment: Can someone help me out? I am still struggling with this. I tried to create a list where I can add the two URI's(in my case, two uri's hit the same api but the resource id changes in the uri). and trying to pass that list to the HttpWebRequest object. But this didn't helped me out.